# VB.net Trim function

Tags: string, vb.net, trim

I have an issue with trim the string method NOT working completely I have reviewed MS Docs and looked of forums but with no luck... It's probably something simple or some other parameter is missing. This is just a sample, 
Please note I need to pick up text before and after #, hence than I was planning to use # as a separator. Trim start @ #, Trim End @ #. I can't use The last Index or Replace per my understanding they have no direction. But perhaps I am misunderstood MS docs regards to trim Start and End as well...
thanks!

```
 Dim str As String = "this is a #string"
        Dim ext As String = str.TrimEnd("#")
        MsgBox(ext)
```

ANSWER:
I found a solution for my problem, if you experience similar please see below:
1st: Trim end will NOT scan for the "character" from the Right as I originally thought it will just remove it from the right.... A weak function I would say:). IndexOf direction ID would be a very simple and helpful. Regards My answer was answered by Andrew, thanks!

Now there is another way around it if you try to split a SINGLE String INTO - QTY based on CHARACTER separation and populate fields accordingly. 
Answer is **ArrayList**. Array List will ID each String so you can avoid repeated populations and etc. After you can use **CASE or IF** to populate accordingly.

```
Dim arrList As New ArrayList("this is a # string".Split("#"c)) ' Will build the list of your strings
Dim index As Integer = 1 ' this will help us index the strings 1st, 2nd and etc.
For Each part In arrList 'here we are going thru the list
Select Case index ' Here we are identifying which field we are populating

       Case 1 '1st string(split)
         MsgBox("1 " & arrList(0) & index) '1st string value left to SPLIT arrList(0). 

       Case 2 '2nd string(split)
         MsgBox("2 " & arrList(1) & index) '2nd string value left to SPLIT arrList(1).  
 End Select

         index += 1 'Here we adding one shift thru strings as we go 

 Next
```

Comment: That is just not what TrimEnd does.  You need LastIndexOf() + SubString()

Comment: There is no "#" at the *end* of that string.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than expecting us to work it out from code that doesn't do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I guess he wants to trim the hash character from the string.

Comment: Why should we have to guess? If we have to guess then it's not a valid question so it should be closed.

Comment: Sure I need to pick characters before "#" and after "#" and populate them in two different table in other words Table 1: This is a, Table 2: string. I have tried LastIndex of but I can't use Last Index. I need to specify direction of Trimming hence comes Start and End, thanks

Comment: jmcilhinney you seemed tense.... You could simply ignore the question. You can split or trim there are many ways to achieve the results. thank you

Comment: @AndrewMorton This looks like the cause.... I thought it would scan from the right until specified character reached, but it simply does it only when character is met, thank you , this clarifies my confusion, Is there a way to scan as Index?

Comment: @Alek If the string was `"part one# part two# part three"`, what do you want to go into table1 and what goes into table2?

Comment: Andrew Morton, I would need : Table 1= Part One, Table 2 = Part Three. Thanks!

Comment: @Alek And what if the string was "part one" with no "#" in it? What goes in table1 and what goes in table2? (P.S. please use an "@" symbol in front of my name to alert me to your comment.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I have finally figured out how to @ thanks! Text Box text. Data is always fixed with separation of #. There are two values separated by #. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
Dim str As String = "this is a #string"
Dim ext As String = str.TrimEnd("#")
```

Try:

```
Dim str As String = "this is a #string"
Dim ext As String = str.Replace("#", "")
```

Comment: Tank you for the answer unfortunately I need to pick up Before and after. I figured if I can have an .END work so is Start would Work. I need to pick up both values and separate them based on position of "#" My plan was to use Trim Start Trim End based on "#" as separation

Comment: Sorry, but that's not defined in the question. You just only meant to trim the hash character in the question.

Comment: Originally I wanted to know why does Trim function doesn't work. But since someone asked to elaborate this is what I did. But I still would like to know why trimming doesn't work on my end, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = "this is a #string"
Dim parts = str.Split("#"c)

For Each part in parts
    Console.WriteLine($"|{part}|")
Next
```

Output:

```
|this is a |
|string|
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried this before. Complication that I have with this after I need to re-evalute the string again for NewlIne if that is even possible) I don't know yet. To populate table 1 with 1st and Table 2 with 2nd, hence then I decide it was easier to trim, thanks

Comment: No idea what you just said but, whatever it was, you certainly didn't mention it in the question. In future, I suggest that you spend a bit more time thinking about the problem and how to describe it in future because we shouldn't have to guess and drag every detail out of you after posting answers to the question you actually asked.

Comment: "trim the string method NOT working completely" - this was an original question.... I do appreciate ALT ways around.... but question as it stands was why TrimEND is NOT working and nothing more, Andrew has clarified this above it is because I misunderstood how function works. I also updated original question per request. Now if I can get a help on how I can Get arrays separated it be great, thanks!

Comment: Meaning by how can I add |this is a| - to 1 table and |string| to 2nd table, thanks

Comment: @Alek `parts` in this answer is an array. If you wanna access it's items, use `part(0)` and `part(1)`.

Comment: @preciousbetine thank you for the answer, I have tried this in 1st table I got "s" New line "h" and in 2nd table "t" it looks like qty from the data, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way as we know there are multiple things to do the same thing.
The solution I used is below:

```
Dim arrList As New ArrayList("this is a # string".Split("#"c)) ' Will build the list of your strings
Dim index As Integer = 1 ' this will help us index the strings 1st, 2nd and etc.
For Each part In arrList 'here we are going thru the list
Select Case index ' Here we are identifying which field we are populating

       Case 1 '1st string(split)
         MsgBox("1 " & arrList(0) & index) '1st string value left to SPLIT arrList(0). 

       Case 2 '2nd string(split)
         MsgBox("2 " & arrList(1) & index) '2nd string value left to SPLIT arrList(1).  
 End Select

         index += 1 'Here we adding one shift thru strings as we go 

 Next
```